# How to run process using a registered application in Azure Active Directory with powershell script

Tags: c#, azure, powershell

I'm trying to create a powershell script that start process with system user account. And I want to use a registered application in AAD as that system user account.

Here the code that I create.

```
$ApplicationId = "My ApplicationID"
$ServicePrincipalSecret = "My Application's secret Key"
$SecurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString –String $ServicePrincipalSecret –AsPlainText -Force
$Credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential ($ApplicationId, $SecurePassword)
Start-Process -FilePath notepad -Credential $Credential
```

this code dose not work. and return following error massage.

> Start-Process : This command cannot be run due to the error: The user
>   name or password is incorrect. At line:1 char:1
>   + Start-Process -FilePath notepad -Credential $Credential
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process], InvalidOperationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand

I tried following command to check my $Credential is correct, and successfully connected Azure. So my Credential object is created properly.

Connect-AzureRmAccount -Credential $Credential -Tenant "My Azure tenant ID" -ServicePrincipal

I also tried following code.

```
$psinfo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
$psinfo.FileName = "notepad"
$psinfo.UserName = $ApplicationId
$psinfo.Password = $SecurePassword
$psinfo.Verb = "runasuser"
$psinfo.UseShellExecute = 0
$psinfo.LoadUserProfile = 0
$ps = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
$ps.StartInfo = $psinfo
$ps.Start()
```

this code dose not work either. and return following error massage.

> Exception calling "Start" with "0" argument(s): "The stub received bad
>   data" At line:1 char:1
>   + $ps.Start()
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Win32Exception

Is there any good way to kick process with a user account that is qualified to manage Azure Active Directory different from a user who actually run the script? if anyone give me any advice will be appreciated.

thanks.

Comment: Have you checked this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36008663/start-process-this-command-cannot-be-run-due-to-the-error-logon-failure-unkn?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below.It worked for me.

```
$uid = "Domain\username"
$pwd = "#pwd"
$Args = "-Verb RunAs -Wait -passthru"
$MyCredential=New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential `
-ArgumentList $Uid, ($pwd | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force)
Start-Process -FilePath C:\windows\system32\system32\notepad.exe -Credential ($cred) -Argumentlist $Args
```

this is for when you want to prompt for credential, else you can simple use below command

```
$MyCredential=New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential `
    -ArgumentList $Uid, ($pwd | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force)
    Start-Process -FilePath C:\windows\system32\system32\notepad.exe -Credential -Credential Get-Credential -Argumentlist $Args
```

Please check this and see if it works for you, else will take a look further with you.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that my problem was because of authentication with non-exist user.
Registered Application in Azure Active Directory wont be synced to Azure Active Directory Domain Service. So even if I tried to perform change/update to AADDS with AAD application service principal credential, authentication failed.
Using AAD User object instead of service principal worked for me.
thanks.